# Normed Vector Space & Compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a real normed vector space.

Let $K$ be a compact set from $V$. Show that the set $2K =$ {2$x$: $x \in K$} is also compact.

A topological space is compact if every open covering has a finite sub-covering.

A norm on V is a function || · || : V → R that satisfies the following three conditions:
(i) ||v|| ≥ 0, ∀ v ∈ V, and ||v|| = 0 ⇔ v = 0;
(ii) ||αv|| = |α| ||v||, ∀ v ∈ V, α ∈ C;
(iii) ||v + w|| ≤ ||v|| + ||w||, ∀ v, w ∈ V

I attempted to prove this using proof by contradiction and assuming the set was not compact but this approach did not get me very far. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U_\alpha$ be an open cover of $2K$. Then ${1 \over 2} U_\alpha$ is an open cover of $K$ and there is a finite subcover ${1 \over 2} U_{\alpha_1},...,{1 \over 2} U_{\alpha_n}$. Hence
$U_{\alpha_1},..., U_{\alpha_n}$ is a finite subcover of $2K$.

A notationally simpler approach is to note that continuous function map compact sets into compact sets, and since $x \mapsto 2x$ is continuous, we see that $2K$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you, that's much cleaner than doing a proof by contradiction. I appreciate your insight!